# Mercurial - cannot commit merge with missing files error

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

I have done a 'hg merge' however when I attempt to do a 'hg commit -m "my msg.." I get the following error message :

```
abort: cannot commit merge with missing files
```

Can anyone explain how to fix this to allow the commit go through?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try `hg status` and look for files in state `!` (missing).

The cause is that one of the files which is part of the merge has been deleted. Undelete the file and try again.

Comment: what if no files have the `!` state?

Comment: @Spongman That shouldn't happen. What file states do you see when you run `hg status`?

Answer (score 14):

Heres my approach

`hg status` will tell you what files are missing. Then you can either restore the file from somewhere

OR type in `hg remove <path/name of missing file>`

THEN commit. Your repo will be sane again, darwin willing.

Comment: This is the answer the worked for me. Had to manually `hg remove` the file. Another "would have just worked in Git" gotchya....

Comment: For me, I couldn't even remove the file with that command because it could not be found. So I just created an empty file of the same missing file name, and it worked for me after that.

Comment: I honestly wouldnt know how HG works in 2022. After Atlassian killed mercurial in Bitbucket, it was the end of the road for me and mercurial. Which is a shame, because I maintain to this day that mercurial is the superior version control system.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TortoiseHG, click in View/Commit. It will show you files in state `!` (missing).

Right click on the file and choose `Revert` (undelete the file) and commit.