# cannot commit merge with missing files

Tags: mercurial

i'm getting this error and I do not know why:

```
% hg commit
abort: cannot commit merge with missing files
```

`hg status` does not show any missing files.

I just spent several hours resolving all my merge conflicts, and now it won't let me commit them. What do I do?

Comment: This would be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070220/mercurial-cannot-commit-merge-with-missing-files-error except that you mention status shows no missing files. Actually, that is mentioned in a comment in that question too but maybe isn't fully addressed.

Comment: Can you post the output of hg status?

Comment: Do you have any aliases for hg status in your hgrc file?